# Strange behavior with literal integer assignment in Visual Studio results in four unexpected compiler errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Copy this exact line and paste it into Visual Studio (i.e. don't type it out, as that will not produce the errors).  It produces the four compiler errors below.  I can't see any invisible characters when I paste it into, e.g., Notepad++.  What is going on?

```
int x = ‭28452;
```

Here are the four compiler errors:

> CS1056 Unexpected character '‭'
>
> CS1002 ; expected
>
> CS1525 Invalid expression term ''
>
> CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: there is unicode U0x8237 char before number

Comment: Where?  Like I said, I've looked at them all in Notepad++ and they're all ASCII.

Comment: check html source

Comment: In case anyone is interested, that value was copied directly from the Windows 10 calculator app.

Comment: There's also an online editor that shows you those hidden characters: https://hexed.it/

Comment: Okay I see it now.  It's actually 8236 not 8237: https://codepoints.net/U+202C

Comment: If I copy and paste into Notepad++ (UTF-8) and change the encoding to ANSII, it changes to: `int x = â€­28452`.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ why wouldn't UTF-8 be sufficient to see it?

Comment: This is so typical Microsoft

Comment: You can use this site https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php to check the characters, there is `U+202D` symbol

Comment: Upvoted because you did the right thing by **cutting and pasting** your code, which allowed us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Wyck, I'm not really new here ;)

Comment: I guess my root problem is I trusted Notepad++ to display hidden characters (with the "show hidden chars" mode on) in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thanks that's definitely worth bookmarking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a character after the = before the assignment
[image]